# Better way for taking multiple inputs with a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I would like to use a for loop to get inputs for many questions I have to receive.
I managed to make some code, but it seems there should be
a better way.
Maybe I can reduce the number of variables I'm using?

```
## <Desired Result>
## onset : 3mo
## location : earth
## character : red
```

```
checks = ['onset','location','character']
l1 = ['onset','location','character']
l2 = ['onset','location','character']

for i in range(len(checks)):
    l2[i] = input(checks[i])

for i in range(len(checks)):
    print(l1[i]+" : "+l2[i])
```

Comment: You don't need to initialize `l2` if you do listcomp: `l2 = [input(x) for x in checks]`. You also don't need `l1` because you never change `checks`.

Answer (score 3):

A few observations on your code:

1. Note that you never actually change `l1` so basically it is unnecessary and wherever you use `l1` replace with `checks`.
2. It is not necessary to define `l2` this way as you are overriding all its values anyway, so you could just define `l2 = []` and then use [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) in your loop:

   ```
   for i in range(len(checks)):
       l2.append(input(checks[i]))
   ```
3. Both your loops have exactly the same range, so you could combine them to 1:

   ```
   for i in range(len(checks)):
       l2[i] = input(checks[i])
       print(l1[i]+" : "+l2[i])
   ```

---

Now, using [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and the [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method of strings, you could actually reduce this code to 3 lines (and get rid of `l1`):

```py
checks = ['onset', 'location', 'character']

l2 = [input(x) for x in checks]

print("\n".join(checks[i]+" : "+l2[i] for i in range(len(checks))))
```

Or more neatly using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
print("\n".join(check + " : " + ans for check, ans in zip(checks, l2)))
```

---

Lastly, to reduce even one more line (and get rid of `l2`):

```py
checks = ['onset', 'location', 'character']

print("\n".join(check + " : " + input(check) for check in checks))
```

---

We could also avoid using `join` and use the chance to further reduce to one line (getting rid of `checks`) using [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)'s extra arguments and [list-unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```py
print(*(check + " : " + input(check) for check in ['onset', 'location', 'character']), sep='\n')
```

Comment: IMO joining on newlines is pointless when you could just loop and print: `for check, ans in zip(checks, l2): print(check + " : " + ans)`

Comment: @wjandrea I would say that's a matter of taste because the point of it is to print, just as the loop so it is not *pointless*. I mean, you could also say that list-comprehensions in general are pointless because you can always just do `for x in y: l.append(x)`

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve for is done using [List comprehensions](https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter6_comprehensions.html).

In your case you can do that in a single line.

```
l2 = [input(x) for x in checks]
```

Answer (score 0):

For a truly 1-line solution to your for-loops, you could do your list comprehension like this:

```
l2 = [(n, print(l1[i]+" : "+n))[0] for i, n in enumerate([input(x + ": ") for x in checks])]
```

Ouput:

```
onseta
locationb
characterc
onset : a
location : b
character : c
```

**EDIT**

As others mentioned, this is not best practice, so use something like this:

```
checks = ['onset','location','character']

l2 = [input(f"Check {n}:\n > ") for n in checks]

print(*(f"{j}: {l2[i]}\n" for i, j in enumerate(checks)), sep="")
```

Output:

```
Check onset:
 > ok
Check location:
 > ok
Check character:
 > ok
onset: ok
location: ok
character: ok
```

Comment: Somethings should not be one lined... This being one of them. Especially when you need to break that line up to meet PEP standards.

Comment: It is not considered good practice to use list-comprehensions for *side-effects* (the prints in this case). List-comprehensions should generally be used if you actually intend to use the list

Answer (score 0):

You should not initialize the list of desired length and take input for each element. You can use `append` method to that.

The following code will help you:

```
checks = ['onset','location','character']
arr = []
for i in checks:
    arr.append(input(i + ' : '))
```

If you want to reduce the number of lines, you can try the following:

```
arr = [ input(i + ' : ') for i in ['onset','location','character']]
```